# SQL - How to have unique constraint on specific values?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints

I want to create a Postgres Table as follows:

```
# First creating enum type
CREATE TYPE POST_TYPE AS ENUM ( 'question', 'option', 'answer')

# Now creating table
CREATE TABLE QNA (
    ...,
    post_id int,
    type POST_TYPE,
    description VARCHAR(100),
    ...
)
```

where `post_id` is a foreign key. What I want to do is:

- I should be able to add only 1 question per foreign key. i.e. (post_id, type) should be unique in the table ONLY in the case when type == 'question'.
- If type is anything else, it need not be unique.

So for example, for some post_id 123:

First insertion: (..., 123, 'question', "", ...) -> should succeed.

Second insertion: (..., 123, 'question', "", ...) -> should fail.

Also, for type != 'question'

insertion: (..., 123, 'option', "", ...) -> should succeed, no matter how many times inserted.

My repositories are already built as per this logic, so I don't want to change the schema. Is there any way to add this constraint in Sql / Postgres?

I tried making (post_id, type) unique together, but that is not allowing me to have multiple 'option' per post_id.

Comment: *I want to create a Postgres Table as follows:* why then tag `mysql`?

Comment: @Stu because this should also be applicable to mysql as well, right?

Comment: then post_id is unique?

Comment: mysql doesn't support types, so the code will be creating an errpr message

Comment: @nbk post_id will not be unique in the table mentioned. All (1 question, multiple options, 1 answer) will be added having the same post_id in the table

Comment: complex condition are better suited to be checked in a trigger, but even there postgres and mysql differ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to create a unique partial index as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX qna_questions_uk ON qna(post_id) WHERE type = 'question';
```

This will resolve the posted question; however, the model should be revised so that the implicit constraints that options and answers have associated questions are addressed. Foreign keys should be used to enforce these constraints, but the example model preculdes their use. Questions, options, and answers are distinct concepts. Modeling them as a single table obscures this.